# OpenGL not rendering with textures

Tags: c++, opengl

My code is not rendering textures onto the triangles it is drawing. The triangles draw in the correct way and the image loading and texturing code has worked when I've used it in other projects.

```
unsigned char* gen_tex(std::string filename, int *texWidth, int *texHeight, int *texChannels)
{
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(("Data/"+filename).c_str(), &*texWidth, &*texHeight, &*texChannels, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO);
    return image;
}

void clean_tex(unsigned char* image)
{
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
}
```

^Image loading and cleaning functions seem to work without issue.

This is the only area of code that relates to the textures and it is run every frame. The triangles themselves appear on the screen correctly but are just drawn using the set glColor

```
int texWidth;
int texHeight;
int texChannels;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

unsigned char* image = gen_tex(std::string("white.png"),&texWidth,&texHeight,&texChannels);

if(texChannels == 4)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
}
else
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
}

clean_tex(image);

for(int i=0; i<tNum; i++)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glTexCoord2f(  0,  0); glVertex3f(triangles[i].A.x, triangles[i].A.y, triangles[i].A.z);
    glTexCoord2f(0.5,0.5); glVertex3f(triangles[i].B.x, triangles[i].B.y, triangles[i].B.z);
    glTexCoord2f(  0,  1); glVertex3f(triangles[i].C.x, triangles[i].C.y, triangles[i].C.z);

    glEnd();
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: What `glGetError()` says? Can you post a minimal complete code?

Comment: glGetError() just ouputs 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the texture as follows:

```
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
```

Not directly related to your issue:

- You should not load the texture every frame, that is very inefficient. Load it only once and reuse between the frames.
- Don't use the immediate mode API. It is legacy and is bad for your health.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a real face palm moment.
I had managed to accidentally delete a call to glColor() and therefore it was drawing the entire thing in that hue. Seeing as I was being a fool and using a plain color texture it was rendering in the wrong color and I kept thinking nothing was appearing.
I forget how stupid I am sometimes. Anyway thanks, problem's now solved.